# input type number shown box in google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, woocommerce

I Have an issue in Google Chrome.I am using WooCommerce and in the product details page there is an input field of type number. My css works fine on other browsers like firefox and safari but it shows a gray box on Google chrome.
Here is an image of this issue [Input Type Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87sOg.png)

```css
.woocommerce .quantity .qty {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: inherit;
  padding: 0 3px;
  width: 5.631em;
}
input[type="number"] {
  background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15.3846px;
}
input[type="number"]:focus {
  border-color: #fab702;
  outline: medium none;
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="cart">
       <div class="quantity buttons_added"><span class="minus sub">-</span>
         <input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="1" name="quantity" max="" min="1" step="1">
           <span class="plus add">+</span>
       </div>
         <input type="hidden" value="111" name="add-to-cart">
           <button class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" type="submit">Add to cart</button>
     </form>
```

Comment: may be your input is disabled ?

Comment: The coded example doesn't have that 'grey' background. Unles syou can demo the problem I'm not sure there is much we can do.